# How can I disable a Function-Key say F4 for a particular application

Tags: input, windows

Consider a business scenario in which a third party's Window Application uses F4 key to auto-fill some inputs with previous record details; and management want to stop this. (no code access on this 3rd party application, all users are in domain, and machine is shared between shift-users)

Now, question is, what would be the best approach to **disable F4 Function-Key just for this particular application**? Writing a process/windows service couldn't works well. Users can kill them from task manager or services explorer.

Any suggestion/Idea ?

Comment: What version of Windows are you running?

Comment: It's Windows Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways you could try this :

(a) enter the BIOS setting, and change the "Function Key Priority"

(b)  Install a new keyboard driver and use its configuration parameters.

(c)  You could map those keys to a program that does nothing. Like : "wscript //b". But, this might affect focus/active window.

(d)  Use the Kid-Key-Lock feature :   http://www.100dof.com/products/kid-key-lock

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion :)
Consider my requirement in which there are hundreds of machines where technical team works in shifts. I need a reliable solution so that these users can't re-enable this F4 key for themselves.